# google map on another page ionic 2

Tags: google-maps, ionic2, cordova-plugins, ionic3

I have been working with the google map plugin whit ionic v2-3, the map works well on the first page, as you can see here:

[image: map on first page]

*FYI: I already installed the plugin and generated the API key*

This is my code:

**map-view.html**

```
<ion-header>

  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>mapView</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>

</ion-header>

<ion-content>
  <button ion-button block (click)="mapa2()">Next Page</button>
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label>Nick</ion-label>
      <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="doc"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label>Password</ion-label>
      <ion-input type="password" [(ngModel)]="pss"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
    <button ion-button full color="primary" (click)="login()">
      Login
    </button>
  </ion-list>
  <div #map id="map" style="height:100%;"></div>
</ion-content>
```

**map-view.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams, Platform } from 'ionic-angular';

import {
 GoogleMaps,
 GoogleMapsEvent,
 LatLng
} from '@ionic-native/google-maps';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-map-view',
  templateUrl: 'map-view.html',
})
export class MapView {

  public doc:string;
  public pss:string;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, 
              public navParams: NavParams, 
              private googleMaps: GoogleMaps, 
              public platform:Platform, 
              public loginCtrl:LoginService) {
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad MapView');
  }

  mapa2(){
    this.navCtrl.push('Map2');
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      this.loadMap();
    });
  }

loadMap() {
let element: HTMLElement = document.getElementById('map');
let map = this.googleMaps.create(element);

    console.log("Inicializo el mapa");


      map.one(GoogleMapsEvent.MAP_READY).then((data:any)=>{
        let myPosition = new LatLng(43.0741904, -89.3809802);
              map.animateCamera({target: myPosition,zoom:10});
              map.addMarker({
                'position':myPosition,
                'title': 'hi!'
              });

      }).catch(()=>console.log("GoogleMap is not available"));
 }
}
```

**On the second page** the map is no longer displayed, but enter in the function:

[image: Second page, does not show the map]

The code (is the same):

**map2.html**

```
<ion-header>

  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>map2</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>

</ion-header>


<ion-content>
  <div #map id="map" style="height:100%;"></div>
</ion-content>
```

**map2.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams, Platform } from 'ionic-angular';

import {
 GoogleMaps,
 GoogleMapsEvent,
 LatLng
} from '@ionic-native/google-maps';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-map2',
  templateUrl: 'map2.html',
})
export class Map2 {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, 
              public platform:Platform, 
              private googleMaps: GoogleMaps) {
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad Map2');
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      this.loadMap();
    });
  }

  loadMap() {
   let element: HTMLElement = document.getElementById('map');
   let map = this.googleMaps.create(element);
    console.log("Inicializo el mapa");


      map.one(GoogleMapsEvent.MAP_READY).then((data:any)=>{
        let myPosition = new LatLng(43.0741904, -89.3809802);
              map.animateCamera({target: myPosition,zoom:10});
              map.addMarker({
                'position':myPosition,
                'title': 'Hi2'
              });

      }).catch(()=>console.log("GoogleMap is not available"));
  }
}
```

How can I show the map on other pages when navigate on the app!

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Try to use the V2 plugin version https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps-doc/blob/master/v2.0.0/README.md .

Answer (score 0):

Hi Andrés Felipe Chaparro,

I had a similar problem in my code.

A possible problem was with '**one**' in `map.one(GoogleMapsEvent.MAP_READY).then((data:any)=>{` **one** will only execute on GoogleMapsEvent.MAP_READY once, when I wanted to use more maps in my application I changed **one** to **on** e.g. `map.on(GoogleMapsEvent.MAP_READY).then((data:any)=>{`

Another possible problem could be the use of **id="map"** in your div. But maybe I'm wrong. When you push a page the next page in the stack will be instantiated, but the page you are pushing from not (yet) destroy as you can go back. It could be the case that in your 2nd page with `document.getElementById('map');` you get the div element of the 1st page, thus not rendering a map on the 2nd page. To see if this is the case you could change the id of the map on the 2nd page to e.g. `<div #map id="map2" style="height:100%;"></div>`

Hope this helps you in any way.